# Ergonomic restatable environment

Tags: theorems, ntheorem

I want to restate several results in a manuscript.
Currently I use `ntheorem` and `thm-restate` with the `restatable` environment, but I am annoyed by how my source looks:

```
\begin{restatable}{theorem}{mytheoremnameaboutfoo}
  \label{thm:my-theorem-name-about-foo}
  ...
\end{restatable}

...

\mytheoremnameaboutfoo*
```

I'd like for it to look like this instead:

```
\begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:my-theorem-name-about-foo}
  ...
\end{theorem}

...

\restate{thm:my-theorem-name-about-foo}
```

What is the best way to write such a macro?
I don't mind all of my environments being restatable, except if it would make compilation extremely slow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to exercise discipline in order for the following code to work: the `\label` which you use for the restatable theorem must be the first `\label` command in the body.

For theorems that you plan to restate, use `\newrestatabletheorem`, with the same syntax as `\newtheorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % but ntheorem might work as well
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newrestatabletheorem}{momo}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{#4}
     {
      \newtheorem{#1inner}{#3}
     }
     {
      \newtheorem{#1inner}{#3}[#4]
     }
   }
   {
    \newtheorem{#1}[#2]{#3}
   }
  \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{o +b}
   {
    \paleka_restate:nnn { #1 } { ##1 } { ##2 }
   }
   {}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\restate}{m}
 {
  \use:c { #1 }*
 }

\seq_new:N \l_paleka_restate_labels_seq
\tl_new:N \l_paleka_restate_label_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \paleka_restate:nnn
 {
  \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { \c{label}\{(.*?)\} } { #3 } \l_paleka_restate_labels_seq
   {% found a label, make restatable
    \__paleka_restate_yes:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
   {% no label found
    \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
     {
      \begin{#1inner}#3\end{#1inner}
     }
     {
      \begin{#1inner}[#2]#3\end{#1inner}
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__paleka_restate_yes:nnn
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \__paleka_restate_noopt:nne { #1 } { #3 } { \seq_item:Nn \l_paleka_restate_labels_seq { 2 } }
   }
   {
    \__paleka_restate_opt:nnne { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { \seq_item:Nn \l_paleka_restate_labels_seq { 2 } }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__paleka_restate_noopt:nnn
 {
  \begin{restatable}{#1inner}{#3}
    #2
  \end{restatable}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__paleka_restate_noopt:nnn { nne }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__paleka_restate_opt:nnnn
 {
  \begin{restatable}[#2]{#1inner}{#4}
    #3
  \end{restatable}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__paleka_restate_opt:nnnn { nnne }
 
\ExplSyntaxOff

% now we can define the restatable theorems
\newrestatabletheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newrestatabletheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Theorems}

\begin{lemma}
  \label{thm:my-theorem-name-about-foo}
  Pigs can fly.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[Negation]
  \label{thm:my-theorem-name-about-foo-negate}
  Pigs cannot fly.
\end{theorem}

\section{Restatements}

\restate{thm:my-theorem-name-about-foo}

\restate{thm:my-theorem-name-about-foo-negate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code examines the body of the environment and extracts the first `\label` command, using its argument for the key to restate the theorem.
In case no `\label` is found, it just typesets the environment.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_jFvbBM71I :)

Comment: Wow. Thanks, I'll try it and accept if it works. By the way, the vertical spacing difference between your two sections is something in your code, or it's something upstream?

Comment: @DanielPaleka I get the same exact output if I use the standard `restatable` environment.